# jQuery: play video on hover

Tags: jquery, html5-video

Looking for better solutions than this:

```
$(".video-post").hover(function () {    
  $(this).find("video").get(0).play();
}, function () {
   $(this).find("video").get(0).pause();     
});
```

-> It works but leads to chrome error:
DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

Theres some articles about this but cant seem to find any simple answer for this. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/06/play-request-was-interrupted

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".video-post").hover(function () {
       $(this).find("video")[0].play();
    }, function () {
        var el = $(this).find("video")[0];
        el.pause();
        el.currentTime = 0;
    });
});
```